# Gensim: Word2Vec Recommender accuracy Improvement

Tags: word2vec, gensim, recommendation-engine

I am trying to implement something similar in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04259.pdf using awesome gensim library however I am having trouble improving quality of results when I compare to Collaborative Filtering.

I have two models one built on Apache Spark and other one using gensim Word2Vec on grouplens 20 million ratings dataset. My apache spark model is hosted on AWS http://sparkmovierecommender.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
and I am running gensim model on my local. However when I compare the results I see superior results with CF model 9 out of 10 times(like below example more similar to searched movie - affinity towards Marvel movies)

e.g.:- If I search for Thor movie I get below results

***Gensim***

- Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)
- X-Men: First Class (2011)
- Rise of the Planet of the Apes (2011)
- Iron Man 2 (2010)
- X-Men Origins: Wolverine (2009)
- Green Lantern (2011)
- Super 8 (2011)
- Tron:Legacy (2010)
- Transformers: Dark of the Moon (2011)

***CF***

- Captain America: The First Avenger
- Iron Man 2
- Thor: The Dark World
- Iron Man
- The Avengers
- X-Men: First Class
- Iron Man 3
- Star Trek
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier

Below is my model configuration, so far I have tried playing with window, min_count and size parameter but not much improvement.

```
word2vec_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
    seed=1,
    size=100, 
    min_count=50, 
    window=30)

word2vec_model.train(movie_list, total_examples=len(movie_list), epochs=10)
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post sample lines from movie_list? Each line should be a set of movies liked by a user. Are you using movie title unique IDs or the name of the movie in your sets?

Comment: its more of movie watched by a user as dataset does not have like feature sample input ['1079', '47', '21', '648', '736', '32', '1', '141', '95', '780', '25', '62', '805', '562', '36', '671', '1356', '29', '748', '802', '733', '832', '14', '637', '1073', '786', '1183', '784', '608', '766', '1357', '494', '1049', '68', '628', '52', '1046', '83', '1111', '4424', '798', '376', '9', '836', '100', '640', '6', '704', '707', '1419', '110', '457', '356', '150', '296', '1080', '380', '260', '288', '198', '1198', '34'] these are list of movies watched by a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention what Collaborative Filtering algorithm you're trying, but maybe it's just better than `Word2Vec` for this purpose. (`Word2Vec` is not doing awful; why do you expect it to be better?)

Alternate meta-parameters might do better.

For example, the `window` is the max-distance between tokens that might affect each other, but the effective windows used in each target-token training randomly chosen from 1 to `window`, as a way to give nearby tokens more weight. Thus when some training-texts are much larger than the `window` (as in your example row), some of the correlations will be ignored (or underweighted). Unless ordering is very significant, a giant `window` (MAX_INT?) might do better, or even a related method where ordering is irrelevant (such as `Doc2Vec` in pure PV-DBOW `dm=0` mode, with every token used as a doc-tag).

Depending on how much data you have, your `size` might be too large or small. Different `min_count`, `negative` count, greater 'iter'/'epochs', or `sample` level might work much better. (And perhaps even things you've already tinkered with would only help after other changes are in place.)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct it is not doing bad may be CF(item 2 item) has edge in this dataset. And I was also thinking that since window size is small it is difficult to infer relationship if there is gap between movie release years primarily because the way I am feeding the dataset in the model (sorted by timestamp).